# Postgres: subdivide table by a field

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis

I have a spatial table with 100 million ish rows. When updating my data, I have often had to update all the rows that fall in some US state. I find that trying to do any operations on the 100 million record table is very slow. All of the rows have a state field (e.g. `state_code=RI`), but I can't figure out how to make good use of it. However, if I create a new table with *just* the rows in the state that needs updating, all read and update operations are very fast (maybe 100x faster).

My question: is there a good way to quickly index by state, or should I just make a different db or table for each state?

Comment: Have you tried using `db_index` [(this)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#db-index) on the `state_code` field?

Comment: I think if you have to change the volume of data regularly, you'd better divide the table.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that I was looking for:
https://blog.timescale.com/scaling-partitioning-data-postgresql-10-explained-cd48a712a9a1